# Need help with a model to optimize a trail in directed graph

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, graphs

The graph in the image represents the production sequencing on a machine with production capacity C in volume.  Each node N represents a different product with a profit L per volume produced.  Every time we pass through node N, a minimum volume of product must be produced.  The objective is to maximize profit.  Note, this is a generalization of the problem, what I'm interested in is a constraint that guarantees that an edge can be passed at most once.  Also, does anyone know if there is a classic problem in the literature that covers the problem?  The closest thing I came to was the vehicle and traveling salesman routing problem, but it's not quite the formulation I need, since nodes can be visited more than once.  I know there is a way to turn the problem into a routing problem, but I wanted an efficient formulation specific to my problem.[image]

Comment: This sounds similar to a network flow problem. Have you read about those?

Comment: It would help to see your attempt at formulating it (in particular what variables you are using).

Comment: It seem Eulerian trail (or Eulerian path) in graph theory, but you have to explain more. Each node has it own capacity, it product is part of the global product ? Exemple: does product of node 1 is the input of production for node 2 ?

Comment: @Maria, do you mean by sequence is something like ($0 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 0$)? Do you have predetermined sequences for all combinations of producing the products? Is it possible the start and the end node being different or should always being the same?